# knowing which hardware causing KMODE EXCEPTION

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

I have windows 8.1 on my asus N55SF, 
recently i had problem with my screen, although i think the problem wasn't in the screen it self, but i guess it had something to do with the intel graphic or the nVidia one, 
the problem is sometimes the screen goes black, with some little white distorted pixel on the left of the screen, and when i gently hit or press somewhere next to the keyboard the screen is back to normal,
but now i never get that problem, instead the screen suddenly gets distorted (but not black screen), 
and after like 2sec i get a blue screen telling me:

```
KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
```

googling that error told me that a code should appear to indicate a status flag or something, but nothing other than the name of the exception appeared.

This problem also happens when i move the laptop (sometimes), and when the fan works at a high speed, so i knew it's not a software problem, 
i also tried to refresh windows, but this problem still occurs.

So how do i know which piece of hardware caused this KMODE_EXCEPTION.

UPDATE:
Dmp Files: https://mega.co.nz/#!oUUSnJhS!sMzy2kPXx-m59R_SCkA8eOJ1oawf2SXWc91VvSj5dCk
UPDATE 2: 
so i did a memtest, i didnt know if it will really end, or go on on testing forever, so i stoped after like an hour, and here is the result
[image]

Comment: Program like BlueScreenViewer allow you to determine what drivers were loaded when the fault happen.

Comment: thank you, nice program, but it gave much a bunch of dlls, and for the `Caused by driver` it says :ntoskrnl.exe

Comment: If its caused by ntoskrnl.exe then its not caused by your `Intel` or `Nvidia` display drivers.

Comment: then what?? what does driver is ntoskrnl.exe? and im pretty sure its not `windows` related problem, cause i tried in linux, and when the fan spins fast, the PC freezes (no blue screen though).

Comment: It's not a driver its the NT kernel...

Comment: is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump and **FORGET** the BlueScreenView crap.

Comment: Of course there is but your summarized explanation of the information displayed by BlueScreenViewer wasn't helpful.  If the computer is freezing while in Linux that indicates a hardware failure.  **My guess something to do with memory**

Comment: @magicandre1981 here's the dmp files: https://mega.co.nz/#!oUUSnJhS!sMzy2kPXx-m59R_SCkA8eOJ1oawf2SXWc91VvSj5dCk

Comment: the dumps show no real cause. check the RAM with memtest86+: http://www.memtest.org/#downiso

Comment: @magicandre1981 ok updated, looking at the result i guess i have a memory error, but how can i know for certain that that is what's causing the problem?

Comment: Because it's not your GPU or cPU so thats all that's left

Comment: @Ramhound ok, i removed the 2Gb ram, and i've been using the pc for quite long time, no crash ... so i guess u were right, since u mentioned the "memory" first, i guess u get the "right answer", write an answer and ill approve it, thank you.

Comment: There are already several questions like this I would rather not, besides, I didn't say anything you didn't already know

Comment: i never thought it could be memory related ... and as you wish, thank you again.